# Android mediaPlayer causing force close onquit

Tags: java, android

My code is force closing as soon as I hit the back button to leave the activity. Here it is.
I think what it does is relatively self explanatory. When called, it shows some text plus a button that when tapped starts a recording playing. When someone hits the back button, it should go back to the previous activity and stop the recording. Thanks for helping me!

```
public class ToBeOrNot extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_be_or_not);

    }
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public void react(View view) {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ToBeOrNot.this, R.raw.achord);
    mediaPlayer.start(); 
}
protected void onStop(){
mediaPlayer.release();
mediaPlayer = null;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_to_be_or_not, menu);
// Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide log-cat error logs, otherwise its pain to look whats wrong.

But i guess you need to.

```
call stop() on media player in onPause()
```

If you want it to keep playing then you need to use service.

Comment: I can't do that, as ADB doesn't work on my laptop and the emulator doesn't work 90% of the time, so I can't give you LogCat errors. If I could, I probably wouldn't need to be asking this question anyway.

Comment: Your example is rather unclearly worded, but I tried changing my onStop() methor to onPause() but that breaks it completely, it won't play the sound and it force closes a few seconds after you try.